# Complex queries across Django reverse generic relations: possible?

Tags: django, django-orm, generic-relations

I have a class `Image` with the following `GenericRelation`:

```
properties = models.GenericRelation(Property)
```

I'm trying to get all Images with certain properties, so I do this:

```
Image.objects.filter(properties__type = "foo", properties__user = request.user)
```

But this results in the following error:

```
DatabaseError: operator does not exist: integer = text
LINE 1: ...perties_property" ON ("myapp_image"."id" = "propert...
                                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is it not possible to query that way? What can I do as an alternative?

Comment: you gave a peace of error ; we could give you a peace of answer in that case but not sure that works ;) you should show us the 2 models too

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do very complex queries over generic relations, then i would rather suggest you write the sql yourself and use raw queries rather. So i guess i would say raw query is an alternative.